# mongoDB adding data to Collections without an _id field

Tags: java, jsp, mongodb, mongodb-java

this is a followup to my previous question on setting up distinct data for Replica sets,
I've found that you can specify a collection for each replica to read, and that you can actually simulate the oplog.rs.

Since these files are different in information the replica will not end up having an error message stating that it's out of sync.

However, the only big problem in my way right now, is the _id field auto generation when you add data to a collection.

Is there a way for me to bypass this _id generation and just add the information into the collection? If not, does the _id field that already shows up inside the document being added get considered as the document _id?

I appreciate your contribution,
Gonçalo

PS: once again, this is part of a java/jsp project and if anyone in the field can assist with functions to do this, please do so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, found the answer to this on the official forums,
for further reference I'll leave the final answer that I got from there.

---

### NOTE: This answer supposedly works according to the mongoDB devs, however, I have not been able to get it to work properly, use at your own discretion and if something wrong happens, well, join in on the bug report fun!

To be able to add documents to a collection without an "_id" field, first we need to create a Capped Collection, this Capped Collection (supposedly and according to the documentation, also, these collections require a max size to be set) gets documents added without an "_id" field by default, in some circumstances however, they might get the "_id" field added anyway, in this case we specify "autoIndexId" as false, this (supposedly) overwrites any defaults and sets the collection to not set the "_id" field as an index, allowing us later on to delete it.

so, to recap, step 1:
we created a Capped Collection:
`db.createCollection("cappedcoll", {capped:true, size:100000});`

step2: 
test the collection to check if it is indeed generating an "_id" field.

if it doesn't generate. why, you're luck! congrats!
if it does generate. step 3:
we create a Capped Collection with the autoIndexId field set to false:
`db.createCollection("cappedcoll", {capped:true, size:100000, autoIndexId:false});`
step4: 
we add an item to the collection and then we remove the "_id" field through an update:

`db.cappedcoll.insert({"names": {"First": "Gonza", "Last": "Vieira"}});
db.cappedcoll.update({"names.First": "Gonza"},{$unset: {"_id":1}});`

if you reach this part, then it either worked or you got a nasty `"cannot modify "_id""` error message, which shouldn't show up, since we set "_id" to not be the index of the collection...

And this also means you're exactly at the same stage as where I am.
Good luck, and I hope they either fix this soon, or someone here complements this post and corrects anything that I've said wrong.

Comment: It still generates _id not matter what you do. I am on version 3.1.